# Scriptable abstract classes

Tags: c#

I made an abstract class and a script provider that compiles scripts using the ScriptDomProvider (the scripts are inheriting from that abstract class). That's how I load them:

```
foreach (var script in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("..\\DataSvr\\Script\\Compiled\\", "*.compiled"))
        {
            var shortname = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(script);

            if (!usedNpcScripts.ContainsKey(shortname))
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + script));
                Type[] types = assembly.GetExportedTypes();

                foreach (Type type in types)
                {
                    if (!GameServer.NpcScripts.ContainsKey(shortname))
                    {
                        GameServer.NpcScripts.Add(shortname, type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So, I get the type of that. Now, my abstract class is named "NpcScript". How can I cast that type to that class so I can call methods from it? Best regards.

Also, Is there a better way to get the script to load? Like, load it into a "NpcScript" type object (the one it inherites from) from the path? Is what I'm doing the correct wsay?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant "create an instance", not "cast", use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This overload takes a `Type` parameter, creates the instance object and returns it to you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to filter out the types. You will do that using [IsSubClassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, then you will instantiate the type using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

So your code will look something like this.

```
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if(!type.IsSubClassOf(typeof(NpcScript)) || type.IsAbstract)
    {
         continue;
    }
    if (!GameServer.NpcScripts.ContainsKey(shortname))
    {
        GameServer.NpcScripts.Add(shortname, type);
    }

    NpcScript myScript = (NpcScript)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    //Do whatever with myScript
}
```